# Adding two integers (range can be greater than long long int) in C

Tags: c

I wrote the following code to add two integers greater than long long int but somehow it seems that it is entering in an infinite loop.

I am only moderately acquainted with the language so the code is a bit clumsy. It will be great if someone points out my mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[127], c[127];
    char b[127], d[127];
    char result[127];
    int i, j, k, l1, l2, sum, carry;
    printf("\n\nenter 1st number\n\n");
    gets(a);
    printf("\n\nenter 2nd number\n\n");
    gets(b);
    l1 = strlen(a);
    l2 = strlen(b);
    //  for(i=0;i<=l1;i++)
    //      printf("%c",a[i]);
    j = l1;
    k = l2;
    /*for(i=l1;i>=0;i--)
    {
    c[j]=a[i];
    j--;
    }
    for(i=l2;i>=0;i--)
    {
    d[j]=b[i];
    j--;
    }*/
    printf("\n%d %d\n", j, k);
    if (l1>l2)
    {
        for (i = l1; i <= l2; i--)
        {
            c[i] = a[j];
            d[i] = b[k];
            j--;
            k--;
        }
        for (i = l2; i <= 0; i--)
        {
            c[i] = a[j];
            d[i] = 0;
            j--;
        }

    }
    //  printf("hello");
    j = l1;
    k = l2;
    if (l1<l2)
    {
        for (i = l2; i <= l1; i--)
        {
            c[i] = a[j];
            d[i] = b[k];
            j--;
            k--;
        }
        for (i = l1; i <= 0; i--)
        {
            c[i] = 0;
            d[i] = b[k];
            k--;
        }
    }
    j = l1;
    k = l2;
    if (l1 = l2)
    {
        for (i = l2; i <= 0; i--)
        {
            c[i] = a[j];
            d[i] = b[k];
            j--;
            k--;
        }
    }
    if (l1>l2)
    {
        for (i = l1; i <= 0; i--)
            printf("%c", c[i]);
    }

    if (l1>l2)
    {
        for (i = l1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i = l1)
                carry = 0;
            else
                /*if(i=l2)
                carry[i]=0;
                else
                carry[i]=sum[i]*/
                carry = sum / 10;
            sum = ((c[i] - '0') + (d[i] - '0')) + carry;
            //  if(i!=0)
            result[i] = sum % 10 + '0';
            //  else
            //      result[i]=sum[i];
        }
        //  for(i=l1-l2;i<=l1;i++)
        //      result[i]=c[i];
    }
    if (l1<l2)
    {
        for (i = l2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i = l2)
                carry = 0;
            else
                carry = sum / 10;
            sum = (c[i] - '0') + (d[i] - '0') + carry;
            //if(i!=0)
            result[i] = sum % 10 + '0';
            //  else
            //      result[i]=sum[i];
        }
        //      for(i=l2-l1;i<=l2;i++)
        //          result[i]=d[i];
    }
    if (l1 = l2)
    {
        for (i = l1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i = l1)
                carry = 0;
            else
                carry = sum / 10;
            sum = (c[i] - '0') + (d[i] - '0') + carry;
            if (i != 0)
                result[i] = sum % 10 + '0';
            else
                result[i] = sum + '0';
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nthe result is\n\n");
    if (l1 >= l2)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= l1; i++)
            printf("%c", result[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= l2; i++)
            printf("%c", result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the indentation (will be visible when someone approves), but please do it properly from now on, it will greatly aid you in debugging your code. And **NEVER** use `gets`; `fgets` is your friend.

Comment: when u have a char array , actually number is not `c[i]` , it is `c[i]-'0'` ..

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should never use `gets` because you cannot specify how many characters it should read; it may very well overflow your buffer. Instead, use `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)`.

The reason why your code is looping forever is all your `if`s are wrong - you're using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`. `=` returns the assigned value, i.e. `if (var = 0)` always returns 0, which means the code inside that `if` will never be executed. When you fix all your `if` statements, you'll discover the next problem:

[image]